# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}}) = 1$

Tags: limits

How can I **prove the following equality**?

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}}) = 1$

With the idea of making use of the following special limit:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}(e^{x}-1) = 1$

I was trying to perform the following substitution: $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

But that was bringing me to this instead:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} - \frac{1}{x}(e^{-x}-1)$

From this point, I can't figure out how to go on.

Comment: Consider $e$ = $(1 + 1/n)^n$ as x tends to infinity

Comment: Where is the equivalence? Or do you mean equality?

Comment: @Atticus yes sorry! Equality

Comment: Do you know the limit definition of $e$ or of $\ln x$?

Comment: The limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}(e^x-1)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x}=1$ can be part of the definition of $e^x$. When that is the case, there is nothing to prove. So, to design a proof we need specifically which definition of $e$, or of $e^{-1/n}$, or of $e^x$ you are working with.

Comment: Your term is not true if it is substituted as $x=\frac1n$. It is $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac1x\cdot \left(1-e^{-x} \right)$$

Comment: @callculus, I think he substituted $x=-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @Atticus Maybe.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help! What I meant is that I have the second equation in the "special limits" table and I was trying to obtain the second one from the first one, but substituting $x = \frac{1}{n}$ does not work. What I did now is substituting the definition of $e$ as most of you suggested me, obtaining $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = 1$. That I assume, proves the first.Thanks again!

Comment: @Robb1 Can you make an edit regarding your substitution?

Comment: @callculus I hope I made it more clear!

Comment: @Robb1 You can do the same as in the answer of Atticus, but for $f(x)=e^{-x}$ .

Comment: You need to be careful with that "substitute the definition of $e$" in the first comment. What you would get is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-\left[\lim_{m\to\infty}(1+1/m)^m\right]^{-1/n})$. You seem to have jumped to this being equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-[(1+1/n)^{n}]^{-1/n})$, but that requires a justification. Not always an iterated limit (along $m$ first and then along $n$) is the same as a limit along the diagonal (along $n=m$).

Comment: Thanks @flan. You are right, I used $n = m$ ... I'll use one of the answers so! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the substitution $n = -1/x$.  Pay attention to the fact that you only approach the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ from the left[1].
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{n}}) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{-1}{x}(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{\frac{-1}{x}}})  \\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{-1}{x}(1-\mathrm{e}^{x})  \\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{1}{x}(\mathrm{e}^{x}-1)  \\
&= 1  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
The last step uses your identity and the implication $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$ implies both $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^{-}} f(x) = L$.

[1]:  This really does matter.  Consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{x}$ and the substitution $x = 1/y$.  Notice that \begin{align*}
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+} \mathrm{e}^{1/y} &= \infty  \text{,}  \\
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} \mathrm{e}^{1/y} &= 0  \text{, so}  \\
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \mathrm{e}^{1/y} &\text{ does not exist.}
\end{align*}
This isn't limited to special functions, like the exponential.  The same thing happens with $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x$ and the same substitution.  Always remember that we only approach $\infty$ and $-\infty$ from one side, so transformed limits are also one-sided limits.

Answer (score 4):

With $x=-\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=e^x$:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}})=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n(1-\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}})=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n(\dfrac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}})=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}$

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

$$n(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}})=\frac{n(e^\frac1n-1)}{e^\frac1n}=\dfrac{n\left(1+\dfrac1n+\dfrac{1}{2n^2}+O(\dfrac{1}{n^3})\right)-n}{e^{\dfrac1n}}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{2n}+O(\dfrac{1}{n^2})}{e^{\dfrac1n}}$$
 It follows the end.